# Get all selected options elements from all select elements in a form

Tags: jquery, select, jquery-selectors

Hi all and thanks for taking the time to answer my question.

I have a form with 6 select elements with the class of "skillLevel". I need to get (preferably in an array] the values of each select element using jQuery.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can use `map` method:

```
var arr = $('select.skillLevel').map(function(){
              return this.value
          }).get()
```

`arr` is an array of values.

Answer (score 16):

```
    var array = [];
    $('.skillLevel  option:selected').each(function() {
        array[ $(this).val()] = $(this).text();
    });
```

Comment: is there a way to get the text sorted as shown in the select(multiple).for example i chose a,b,c i get the displayed c,a,b..

Answer (score 7):

Something like this will do that for you.

```
var val = new Array();

$("select.skillLevel").each(function(){
    val.push(this.value);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Use it as

```
$(".skillLevel option:selected").each(function () {
            alert($(this).text());
});
```

Check out this Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/zF6HY/1/

Courtesy from : [JqueryApi](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/)

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the `map` method with an ES6 arrow function like this.

```
var arr = $('select.skillLevel').get().map(e => e.value)
```

As in the accepted answer, `arr` is an array of values.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this fiddle will help you :
[All selected options](http://jsfiddle.net/ravi441988/AqUN7/)

Answer (score 1):

I think that you have to use `$(".skillLevel")` to select all the elements you want the value, and then iterate over them, and use `.val()` to extract the value of every element, and treat it as you want.

Hope this helps!