# Accessing the select_tag selected value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, html-select

Well, I have multiple **select_tag** (the values are generated from a splitted single string), here:

```
<% @item.item_options.each do |x| %>
    <% if !x.value.empty? && !x.option.empty? %>
    <div class="row"> <%= x.option %> : <%= select_tag :values, options_for_select(x.value.split(',')) %></div>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I'm trying to concatenate only the selected values from each one into one string. And separate them by a spacial character and pass it to a different controller.

I'm using a **hidden_filed** to send the values but I'm not able to access the selected values to do the concatenation!

```
<%= f.hidden_field :values, :value => ??? %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jquery to get the selected value of a select:

```
$('select option:selected').val();
```

if I understood properly your question.

To get all selected options elements from all select elements look here:

[Get all selected options elements from all select elements in a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12457891/get-all-selected-options-elements-from-all-select-elements-in-a-form)

Comment: thank you. I'll give it a try. I was hoping for a way to do it in rails.